# Is there a usefull way to monitor SQL Server connections activity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection, monitor

I'm developing a C# application which will monitor SQL Server connections activity.

The kind of information I would like to monitor:

- Process id which established a connection
- queries and actions performed by the connected process

Is there a programmable way?

Asaf.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server already offers this, via [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15). Just follow the tutorial [Monitor System Activity Using Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/monitor-system-activity-using-extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15). The fact that you want to do this from C# is completely irrelevant.

Comment: If you want to stream the events directly to your C# app, or read an .xel file in your app, use this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.XELite/

Answer (score 3):

You can use **SQL Server Profiler**

> SQL Server Profiler is an interface to create and manage traces and analyze and replay trace results. Events are saved in a trace file that can later be analyzed or used to replay a specific series of steps when trying to diagnose a problem.

first you need to start **SQL Server Profiler**

[image]

Then make the following settings in the **Events Selection** section,then  You can see the query that goes to sql

[image]

Then: Run **SQL Server Profiler**

[image]

Tutorial:[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15)